# Last char in scanf

Tags: c

I am scanning from stdin input from user that looks like

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
```

code which i am using is  pretty simple

```
int main ( void ) { 
  char d;
  int i;
  while(1){
    scanf("%c %d",&d,&i);
    printf("%c %d",d,i);    
  }
```

but the output is always without last curly bracket e.g

```
input = { 1, 70, 8,  1 }
output = { 1, 70, 8, 1 1
```

while i want to output be exactlrey the same and store numbers in the array, do you have any ideas how to fix this unwanted behavior<

Comment: We need to see more of the code...

Comment: Your code can only read zero or more sets of "character followed by a number". But your input does not consist of zero or more sets of "character followed by a number" since no number follows the `}` character. So how could this possibly work?

Comment: Or, to put it another way, what in your code could possibly sensibly read and output a character not followed by a number, such as the `}` at the end? As for how to fix it, just read a line and print it back out. If that doesn't meet your requirements, it's because you didn't tell us what they are.

Comment: im aware of it but not sure how to fix it ,thats why im asking here for help

Comment: So is your question "How do I read a line of input and print it back out?"

Comment: you are right i forgot to mention that i want to store numbers in the array.

Comment: @Abdir explore the option of `fgets` if you want to store in array.

Comment: @Abdir Ah, so your question is, "How do I read a line in and parse it, extracting numbers and delimiters?"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
char d;
int i;
while(1){
    scanf(" %c", &d);
    if(d == '}'){
        printf(" %c\n", d);
        break;//or continue;
    }
    else
        ungetc(d, stdin);
    scanf(" %c %d", &d, &i);
    printf("%c %d", d, i);
}
```

Comment: The basic idea is that compared `'}'` with the read character. `ungetc` can remove by dividing the input.